# Get the size of a window in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv

I have searched online and wasn't able to find an answer to this so I figured I could ask the experts here. Is there anyway to get the current window resolution in OpenCV? I've tried the cvGetWindowProperty passing in the named instance of the window, but I can't find a flag to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are able to set the size of an OpenCV window, so could you please clarify why you need to get the size? The implication being that if you've already created it and/or resized it, then you should be able to know its size already.

Comment: I am running some algorithms in the background that rely on the screen resolution. Whether the feed is from a video or a webcam I would require the size information. I could always hard code the size and work off of that, but if I load in a different video on the fly or if I am taking in various webcam resolutions I would like to grab the information out automatically rather then setting a set size for everything.

Comment: @aardvarkk for example, for preserving window geometry for the next algorithm iteration (user could change window size) after window destroying.

Comment: Answer is over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041607/getting-screen-size-on-opencv :  uses a macro on Win32/not, and then GetSystemMetrics or XOpenDisplay + DefaultScreenOfDisplay

Answer (score 5):

You can get the **width** and **height** of the contents of the window by using **shape[1]** and **shape[0]** respectively.
I think when you use Open CV, the image from the camera is stored as a Numpy array, with the shape being [rows, cols, bgr_channels] like [480,640,3]

code e.g.

```
import cv2 as cv2

cv2.namedWindow("myWindow")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #open camera
ret,frame = cap.read() #start streaming

windowWidth=frame.shape[1]
windowHeight=frame.shape[0]
print(windowWidth)
print(windowHeight)

cv2.waitKey(0) #wait for a key
cap.release() # Destroys the capture object
cv2.destroyAllWindows() # Destroys all the windows


console output:
640
480
```

You could also call **getWindowImageRect()** which gets a whole rectangle: x,y,w,h

e.g.

```
import cv2 as cv2

cv2.namedWindow("myWindow")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #open camera
ret,frame = cap.read() #start streaming

windowWidth=cv2.getWindowImageRect("myWindow")[2]
windowHeight=cv2.getWindowImageRect("myWindow")[3]

print(windowWidth)
print(windowHeight)

cv2.waitKey(0) #wait for a key
cap.release() # Destroys the capture object
cv2.destroyAllWindows() # Destroys all the windows

-which very curiously printed 800 500 (the actual widescreen format from the camera)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... it's not really a great answer (pretty hack!), but you could always call `cvGetWindowHandle`. With that native window handle, I'm sure you could figure out some native calls to get the contained image sizes. Ugly, hackish, and not-very-portable, but that's the best I could suggest given my limited OpenCV exposure.